# LowLevelKeyboardProc processing modifier keys only on key release

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I see some strange behaviour of low-level keyboard hook callback.

First, I install the hook in a proper way

```
hook_handle_ = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
```

After that I expect WM_KEYDOWN on key press

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*  kbd = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
            std::cout << "Code = " << kbd->vkCode << " Scan = " << kbd->scanCode << " Flags = " << kbd->flags << '\n';
            break;
        }
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*  kbd = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
            std::cout << "Code = " << kbd->vkCode << " Scan = " << kbd->scanCode << " Flags = " << kbd->flags << '\n';
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When I press, let's say Left Ctrl, I expect a message WM_KEYDOWN, but receive nothing. However, when I release the Left Ctrl, I get both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP

> Code = 162 Scan = 29 Flags = 0
>
> Code = 162 Scan = 29 Flags = 128

I need a way to catch a press event separately, not press and release.
Is there a way to do it? Not necessary those tools I use.
Thanks.

Update: it happen to modifiers only, like Ctrl, Shift, Alt, other keys are processed as expected

Comment: strange. windows and send this events separately. say if you press and hold Left Ctrl you got several WM_KEYDOWN(Code = 162 Scan = 29 Flags = 0) and finally (after release) WM_KEYUP (Code = 162 Scan = 29 Flags = 128)

Comment: Holding a key down does issue multiple `WM_KEYDOWN` messages.  In the actual messages that are delivered to a window, there is a repeat count that increments with each message until the key is released. That repeat count is not provided in the LLKH flags.  You would need to use a `WH_GETMESSAGE` or `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook to process the window messages so you can see the value of the repeat count.

Comment: I normally get multiple WM_KEYDOWN on all keys - except modifiers